# Idiomatic haskell database connectivity

Tags: sql, haskell

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801586/idiomatic-haskell-for-database-abstraction) post I asked about what would be idiomatic haskell database abstraction. I had been thinking for it a while, and the first answer was similar to what I had in mind, and I wrote a proof-of-concept of it. Discarding the abomination that is the schema, what would you change, and why?

Database.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Database (
    runDB
  , quickQuery
  , prepare
  , execute
  , fetchRowAl
  , DB (..)
  , module Database.HDBC.SqlValue
) where
import qualified Database.HDBC as H
import Database.HDBC.SqlValue
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Control.Monad.Reader

newtype DB a = D (ReaderT Connection IO a) deriving (Monad, MonadReader Connection, MonadIO)

runDB ::  FilePath -> DB b -> IO b
runDB path (D x) = do
  c <- connectSqlite3 path
  mkSchema c
  r <- runReaderT x c
  H.disconnect c
  return r

mkSchema conn = do
  tables <- H.getTables conn
  unless ("Location" `elem` tables) $ do
    H.handleSqlError $ H.quickQuery' conn "CREATE TABLE Location (location TEXT PRIMARY KEY)" []
    return ()
  unless ("Person" `elem` tables) $ do
    H.handleSqlError $ H.quickQuery' conn (unwords [
        "CREATE TABLE Person"
      , "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
      , "name TEXT NOT NULL,"
      , "age INT NOT NULL,"
      , "location TEXT,"
      , "FOREIGN KEY (location) REFERENCES Location (location))"]) []
    return ()

quickQuery :: String -> [SqlValue] -> DB [[SqlValue]]
quickQuery q v = ask >>= \c -> liftIO $ H.quickQuery c q v

prepare :: String -> DB H.Statement
prepare q = ask >>= \c -> liftIO $ H.prepare c q

execute :: H.Statement -> [SqlValue] -> DB Integer
execute stmt v = liftIO $ H.execute stmt v

fetchRowAl :: H.Statement -> DB (Maybe [(String, SqlValue)])
fetchRowAl = liftIO . H.fetchRowAL
```

Model.hs

```
module Model where

import Database

data Person = Person (Maybe Int) String Int Location
newtype Location = Location String deriving (Eq)

instance Eq Person where
  (Person _ a b c) == (Person _ a' b' c') = a == a' && b == b' && c == c'

saveLocation ::  Location -> DB ()
saveLocation (Location x) = quickQuery "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Location VALUES (?)" [toSql x] >> return ()

retrieveLocation :: String -> DB (Maybe Location)
retrieveLocation x = do
  r <- quickQuery "SELECT location FROM Location WHERE location=?" [toSql x]
  case r of
       [] -> return Nothing
       [[y]] -> return $ Just $ Location $ fromSql y

savePerson :: Person -> DB ()
savePerson (Person _ n a l@(Location loc)) = do
  saveLocation l
  quickQuery "INSERT INTO Person (name, age, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" [toSql n, toSql a, toSql loc]
  return ()

retrievePersons name = do
  r <- quickQuery "SELECT id, name, age, location FROM Person WHERE name=?" [toSql name]
  let persons = map makePerson r
  return persons
  where
    makePerson [sid, sname, sage, slocation] =
      Person (fromSql sid) (fromSql sname) (fromSql sage) (Location (fromSql slocation))
```

tests.hs

```
import Test.HUnit
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Test.Framework (defaultMain, testGroup)
import System.Directory
import Database.HDBC (quickQuery')
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe
import Database
import Model

runTest f = runDB "/tmp/test.db" f <* removeFile "/tmp/test.db"

testConnected = runTest $ do
  c <- ask
  r <- liftIO $ quickQuery' c "SELECT 'foo' AS value" []
  liftIO $ assertBool "Return value should not be empty" (length r > 0)

testQuickQuery = runTest $ do
  [[x]] <- quickQuery "SELECT ? AS value" [toSql "foo"]
  liftIO $ assertBool "quickQuery" (fromSql x == "foo")

testPrepared = runTest $ do
  stmt <- prepare "SELECT ? AS value"
  execute stmt [toSql "foo"]
  (Just r) <- fetchRowAl stmt
  let (Just x) = lookup "value" r
  liftIO $ assertBool "prepared" (fromSql x == "foo")

testRetrieveLocationNothing = runTest $ do
  r <- retrieveLocation "Turku"
  liftIO $ assertBool "Location nothing" (isNothing r)

testSaveLocation = runTest $ do
  let turku = Location "Turku"
  saveLocation turku
  (Just loc) <- retrieveLocation "Turku"
  liftIO $ assertBool "loc == turku" (loc == turku)

testSavePerson = runTest $ do
  let person = Person Nothing "Person" 25 $ Location "Turku"
  savePerson person
  [per] <- retrievePersons "Person"
  liftIO $ assertBool "model == db" $ validate person per
  where
    validate _ (Person Nothing _ _ _) = False
    validate a b = a == b

tests = [
    testGroup "Database" [
        testCase "connected" testConnected
      , testCase "quickQuery" testQuickQuery
      , testCase "testPrepared" testPrepared
    ]
  , testGroup "Model" [
        testCase "saveLocation" testSaveLocation
      , testCase "savePerson" testSavePerson
      , testCase "testRetrieveLocationNothing" testRetrieveLocationNothing
    ]
  ]

main = defaultMain tests
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I spotted a bug: since HDBC implicitly runs queries in a transaction, and since you never [commit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/latest/doc/html/Database-HDBC.html#v%3acommit), none of your changes are actually applied to the database.  Add a test that opens the file again, to make sure changes persist.

Now, on to code structure.

I definitely like the use of a reader monad.  Not only does it keep the user from having to pass a `Connection` around, but it confines database operations to a single thread (if I understand correctly, SQLite3 does not support concurrent access to a single connection handle, nor does HDBC-sqlite3 provide mutual exclusion).  However, since the `MonadReader Connection` instance is exposed, a user could still get at the underlying `Connection` and do something to it in another thread.  I wouldn't be too worried about that, through.

You may want to leverage the type system some more.  For example, consider defining a type class for records that can be stored and retrieved:

```
class Record r where
    insert :: r -> DB Int -- returns the ID of the inserted row
    get    :: Int -> DB (Maybe r)
```

Better yet, use [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) to keep ID types distinct:

```
newtype Id record = Id {unId :: Int}
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

class Record r where
    insert :: r -> DB (Id r)
    get    :: Id r -> DB (Maybe r)
```

However, there's a problem: the `Location` table's primary key is `TEXT`, not `INT`.  If it were up to me, I'd give the `Location` table an integer primary key, so that:

- All records have a consistent ID type
- Locations can be renamed without violating the foreign key constraint.
- The `Person` table doesn't duplicate location names.  You don't want your database blowing up when 200 people take a field trip to [Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll).

I recommend reading the [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) chapter of the Yesod book.  Even if you don't use Persistent, look at how it's designed.

For example, I noticed you embedded the ID field in your `Person` type:

```
data Person = Person (Maybe Int) String Int Location
```

Persistent chooses to keep the ID and data separate.  The [Insert section](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#file337-insert-x1) gives a convincing rationale.

Persistent also runs its database monad in a single transaction ([see the PersistBackend section](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#file328-persistbackend-bc5)).  HDBC implicitly runs everything in a transaction, so you don't have to do much to follow suit.  This approach has a semantic benefit.  Sometimes, you need to do a group of operations atomically.  Rather than calling BEGIN and COMMIT explicitly (and hoping the caller isn't also doing stuff in a transaction), you use the type system to force the code to run inside of a transaction.

[STM](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Software_transactional_memory) does something similar: you can't nest transactions without sidestepping the type system (e.g. with `unsafePerformIO`).